# Unable to send Teams messages to Echo Bot with "Upload Custom Apps" AKA side-loading enabled

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-teams

I created a simple C# Web App Echo Bot based on this tutorial [Create a bot with Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).  I selected the Echo Bot template and created the bot through the resource form.

Once deployed, the bot behaves as expected with the "Test in Web Chat" browser interface.  However, after integrating the Teams channel by clicking on the Web App Bot resource Channels > Teams > Save and accepting the user agreement, I am unable to send messages using the Channels > Teams > Browser interface.  The input message box is disabled with text "Sending new messages to this bot has been disabled by your administrator".  The bot icon has a red "do not enter" icon too.

Prior to deploying the bot, I had gone to the Teams admin center > Teams Apps > Setup Policies and enabled "Upload custom apps" (AKA enable side-loading according to the info bubble).  This was done for the Global org-wide defaults.  Also, it was done several days beforehand so latency of applied settings would not be an issue.

I am doing this on an Office 365 Dev account.

What do I have to do to integrate a simple bot to Microsoft Teams?

Comment: Can you verify that the steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant all look good? If so, can you please reach out to us via the email address available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback (we made need your tenant Id to pull the appropriate logs)

Comment: It looks like we just deployed a fix for this globally; the error message should go away now and you should be able to interact with your bot as expected.

Comment: @AndrewClear: thank you!  Yes, I did follow the "get started" steps.  Teams were enabled in O365Dev and in Teams Admin Center all custom app settings were enabled for User, Team, and Org.  At first your fix did not work for my already deployed and Team channel integrated EchoBot, so I deleted and deployed another.  The second one failed to respond and I was left with a "Just Me" conversation after sending "hi".  The third EchoBot deploy I waited a few minutes after Teams integration before testing,   hypothesizing a latency issue.  It then worked as it should.

Comment: @AndrewClear: Not sure on etiquette, but if you post your comment on MSFT bug fix as answer, I will mark as the answer.  Sorry, not able to upvote comments.